# Funcion sacar_compras() realiza la resta de productos incorrectamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, diccionarios

Tengo una funcion `sacar_compras()` (la cual dejo acá abajo) que, a la hora de realizar una resta en la cantidad de productos que deseo sacar de mi lista de compras `compras = {}`, me acumula los valores que deseo restar, por lo que a ciertos elementos les resta mas de lo que debería.

Voy con un ejemplo para que sea mas claro.

Supongamos que mediante la función agregar, agrego 5 manzanas y 7 bananas a `compras = {}`. Cuando yo quiera restar, digamos, 2 bananas, me la restara, pero luego si quiero restar 2 manzanas, me restara 4 (ya que se acumularon los valores de resta como dije antes).

Si alguien puede ver el error en el código, se lo agradecería muchísimo. Desde ya aclaro, soy principiante en Python, por lo que el código es muy básico. Gracias!

```
compras = {}

def agregar_compras():
global nombre_compras
global cantidad_compras
usuario = None
while usuario != "no":
    usuario = input("Desea agregar un elemento a la lista de compras? (si o no): ")
    if usuario == "si":
        nombre_compras = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
        print(nombre_compras)
        cantidad_compras = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad a comprar: "))
        if cantidad_compras == 0:
            print("Ingrese una cantidad mayor a 0!")
        print(cantidad_compras)
        compras[nombre_compras] = cantidad_compras
        #codigo que realiza la accion
        print("Producto agregado")
        print(compras)
    if usuario == "no":
        print("Funcion terminada, elementos removidos")
    # funciona correctamente

def sacar_compras():
global nombre_compras
global cantidad_compras
usuario = None
while usuario != "no":
    usuario = input("Desea remover un elemento a la lista de compras? (si o no): ")
    if usuario == "si":
        nombre_compras = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
        print(nombre_compras)
        cantidad_compras_remover = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad a remover: "))
        resta = cantidad_compras - cantidad_compras_remover
        print("Solamente se deben comprar", resta, "unidades de", nombre_compras)
        # falla una parte de esto, ya que no resta correctamente
        cantidad_compras = resta
        compras[nombre_compras] = cantidad_compras
        # esta es la linea de codigo que hace que compras luego quede modificada con la nueva cantidad del producto a comprar
        # o por lo menos con dentro de esta funcion
        print(compras)
        if resta <= 0:
            del compras[nombre_compras, cantidad_compras]
            # aca es donde se genera el error, no puede eliminar el elemento por alguna razon, pienso que es porque cantidad_compras es 0 quizas.
            print(compras)
    if usuario == "no":
        print("Funcion terminada, elementos removidos")
```

Answer (score 0):

Es normal que no funcione, te falta buscar dentro del diccionario cuando quieres quitar un producto concreto cual es su cantidad, tampoco cambias la cantidad de compras, siempre va a tener el ultimo valor del producto que agregues el ultimo. Para recorrer el diccionario de compras apóyate en esto:

```
valores = {'platano': 4, 'naranja': 3, 'sandia': 8}
# k es key, que hace referencia a los nombres de los productos
# v hace referencia a values, que en ese caso son las cantidades
for k, v in valores.items():
    print('k=', k, ', v=', v)
k=platano, v=4
k=naranja, v=3
k=sandia, v=1
```

Repasa todas las variables y como las utilizas pues ahí radica el problema. Separa cuales son las cantidades de cada producto, a qué se lo restas y cómo y cuándo lo asignas.

He podido ver esto así de primeras después de un pulido al código te podré decir mas si lo actualizas.

Answer (score 0):

no tenías implementado la llamada al diccionario . Y poner en la resta el valor que tenía menos el valor a restar. También la condición si es menor o igual a 0 podrías hacer un except , estaría más funcional o incluso meterlo en un while para no restar menos de lo que hay de stock

```
compras = {}

def agregar_compras():
  global nombre_compras
  global cantidad_compras
  usuario = None
  while usuario != "no":
    usuario = input("Desea agregar un elemento a la lista de compras? (si o no): ")
    if usuario == "si":
      nombre_compras = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
    print(nombre_compras)
    cantidad_compras = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad a comprar: "))
    if cantidad_compras == 0:
        print("Ingrese una cantidad mayor a 0!")
    print(cantidad_compras)
    compras[nombre_compras] = cantidad_compras
    #codigo que realiza la accion
    print("Producto agregado")
    print(compras)
    print(compras.get(nombre_compras))
if usuario == "no":
    print("Funcion terminada, elementos removidos")
# funciona correctamente

def sacar_compras():
  global nombre_compras
  global cantidad_compras
  usuario = None
  while usuario != "no":
    usuario = input("Desea remover un elemento a la lista de compras? (si o no): ")
    if usuario == "si":
      nombre_compras = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
    print(nombre_compras)
    cantidad_compras_remover = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad a remover: "))
    resta = compras.get(nombre_compras)-cantidad_compras_remover
    print("Solamente se deben comprar", resta, "unidades de", nombre_compras)
    # falla una parte de esto, ya que no resta correctamente
    cantidad_compras = resta
    compras[nombre_compras] = cantidad_compras
    # esta es la linea de codigo que hace que compras luego quede modificada con la nueva cantidad del producto a comprar
    # o por lo menos con dentro de esta funcion
    print(compras)
    if resta <= 0:
        del compras[nombre_compras, cantidad_compras]
        # aca es donde se genera el error, no puede eliminar el elemento por alguna razon, pienso que es porque cantidad_compras es 0 quizas.
        print(compras)
if usuario == "no":
    print("Funcion terminada, elementos removidos")
```